# What's the minimal code required to have two local instances communicate with Akka actors?

Tags: scala, networking, messaging, actor, akka

I wonder what's the minimal code required to start two instances of an application on a machine, which can send to and receive messages from each other.

As far as I understand, I would need

1. to start an actor which can process messages.
2. to tell this instance that there is another instance where messages can be sent to.

How can I do 1. and 2. in Akka?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Akka's home page](http://akka.io/):

```
// server code
class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg => self reply (msg + " World")
  }
}
remote.start("localhost", 2552).register("hello-service", actorOf[HelloWorldActor])

// client code
val actor = remote.actorFor("hello-service", "localhost", 2552)
val result = (actor ? "Hello").as[String]
```